# Convert characters to Ascii

Tags: filter, escaping

Is there a twig filter to encode special characters like umlauts:
`{{ entry.title | filter }}`

> Datensätze & Karten

Which then should result in:

> datensaetze-karten

Basically what `'convertFilenamesToAscii' => true,` [does](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#convertFilenamesToAscii) but as a filter.

I want to use this as a anchorlink later on so umlauts are not the best to have in anchor links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a combination of things:

- Twig's [replace](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html) filter to convert `ä` to `ae` etc.
- Twig's [convert_encoding](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/convert_encoding.html) filter to eliminate any remaining non-ascii characters
- Craft's [kebab](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#kebab) filter to do its thing

and of course wrap the thing up in a macro

```
{% macro ascii_kebab(s) %}
  {{ s
    | replace({
        'ä': 'ae'
      })
    | convert_encoding('ASCII', 'UTF-8')
    | kebab
  }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! BTW: in craft 3 macros cannot contain dashes.

Comment: @outline4 whoops! removed the dash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Craft's `|ascii` Twig Filter, [which was added in Craft 3.1.25](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/CHANGELOG-v3.md#3125---2019-04-30), for this:

```
{{ entry.title|ascii }}
```